# Slurm array spawning multiple tasks for same job

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hpc, slurm

So I have this python script which uses multiprocessing, and it has 4 ways of running, depending on the environmental variable APP_TYPE, that it reads during runtime.

Therefore, I am using `slurm --array` to make it parallel. The issue is that instead of it spawning 4 jobs, each with its own task (run python script in mode A/B/C/D using all node cores), it is spawning for times each task. I.e, I run `sbatch batch.sh` and it spawns 4 tasks in each job. Note that I am looking forward to run each job on each node once, so that I can use all cores of a node on multiprocessing (in this case 28 cores per node).

After running sbatch I get the message: `Submitted batch job 11200`
I can see 4 log files:

- `slurm_job_11200_0.log`
- `slurm_job_11201_0.log`
- `slurm_job_11202_0.log`
- `slurm_job_11203_0.log`

However, each of the logs say the repeated message. For log `slurm_job_11200_0.log`

```
python script started in mode A, pid 2222
python script started in mode A, pid 5555
python script started in mode A, pid 3333
python script started in mode A, pid 1111
```

What do I need to change to stop this repetition?

Thanks!

Here is the slurm script

```
#!/bin/bash

# SLURM Configuration
#SBATCH --job-name="job"
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=28
##SBATCH --exclusive

#SBATCH --mem=32000 #(32G not working?)
#SBATCH --output=slurm_job_%j_%t.log
#SBATCH --error=slurm_job_%j_%t.log
#SBATCH --array=0-3

task_command="python script.py $@"
modes=(A B C D)


echo "==================== START JOB $SLURM_JOB_ID: $SLURM_JOB_NAME ===================="

export APP_TYPE="${modes[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"

srun $task_command; t1_exit_code=$?


echo "==================== END JOB $SLURM_JOB_ID: $SLURM_JOB_NAME ===================="
exit $t1_exit_code
```

Bonus question: why I cant use `32G` for ram? the documentations says we can use G for the memory unit

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove `#SBATCH --nodes=4`. This line, along with the use of `srun`, actually instructs each job of the array to run the same Python script on four different nodes.

(And of course the `script.py` script must enquiry the value of the environment variable `APP_TYPE` as it is not passed as argument.)